# How to create Azure Communication Service Group call via C#/MVC

Tags: azure-communication-services

Good day

I would love to create Azure Communication Service group call via C#/MVC just like on this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/samples/calling-hero-sample?pivots=platform-web

How can I achieve this?